# split screen and run 2 different activities on android

Tags: android, multitasking

I'm developing an android app that needs 2 separate activities running at the same time, they both have their own layout. What i am doing right now is creating 2 different intents and start them in sequence. But it looks like they are not running at the same time, I have to quit the first activity to start the second one.
Can someone help me with this issue? If I can display 2 activities at the same time using split screen, that will be awesome.
Thank you!

Comment: It seems that your question has been answered, could you accept the appropriate answer? Also, you haven't accepted a single answer to any of your questions. You do know that you should accept answers, right?

Comment: sry i dont know, doing it right now, will never happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are your needs for the project? You can setup a single layout with 2 RelativeLayouts overlapping, and just bringToFront the one that you will need, and use Threads to do your processing. Not clean, but it would work.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). They were originally designed with a different goal in mind, but they might work for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm developing an android app that needs 2 separate activities running at the same time

That is not supported by the stock Android OS at this time. You will need to come up with some other solution for whatever problem you think you have. Fragments, as Mr. Cherkashyn mentions in his answer, would be one candidate.

> What i am doing right now is creating 2 different intents and start them in sequence. But it looks like they are not running at the same time, I have to quit the first activity to start the second one.

Correct.

> Can someone help me with this issue?

Step #1: Download the Android source code.

Step #2: Modify the OS to support displaying two activities at once.

Step #3: Compile your revised OS and put it into a ROM mod.

Step #4: Install that ROM mod on the device of your choice.

Comment: You forgot to make patch and push it to the Android repo again. Multiwindows support is the only missed feature on my N7.

Comment: @Leandros: Yeah, well, I suspect the patch won't get accepted. Not that Google would necessarily be opposed to the feature, but it is core enough that they'll want to implement it themselves. Samsung's S-Apps (or whatever they call it) demonstrate that is at least possible in part.